# php header() syntax for meta name & content

Tags: php

I've been trying to get the php header() to work with the following meta tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and whatever I try, I just cannot get this to work.  I'd like to add this in addition to `header("refresh: 15; url=/about.html");` - which does work - so that the view is decent on a mobile device.

I'm also curious about:

```
<meta name="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
```

In my feeble attempts to get this to work, I've tried adding

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
header("X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge");
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

thinking this might cause or at least contribute to the problem, but no luck.

I'd greatly appreciate any feedback or suggestions.

Thanks a ton!!

Comment: How did you expect that `header()` would work with `meta` tags?

Comment: i am stuck, are you trying to create a new version of php??

Comment: Just do `echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">';` ?

Comment: The headers you are sending have no whatsoever correlation to the `<meta>` tags...

Comment: Ronser, thank you for all that detailed information.  For now, I will just use the echo, like you and Shane Smith detailed, since that's the easiest, particularly since this is for a page that's not central to the site (email sent confirmation).  I will use your suggestions going forward for other pages.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

you can use header like

```
header("refresh: 15; url=/about.html"); //for delay
header("location:about.html");
```

you cant use

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
header("X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge");
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

if you want to add meta tag

use:

```
if(somecondition)
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />';
     // dynamic as follows...
    //echo '<meta name="'.$metaName.', content="'.$metaContent.'"';
else
    echo '<meta name="keywords" content="" />';
```

if your consideration is to align your site proper in web and mobile devices

```
@media (min-width: 700px) { your css styles }

@media (min-width: 300px) and (orientation: landscape) {  your css styles  }
```

[and many more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)